# How to retrieve value using jq

Tags: jq

Below is the JSON we have, and I want to filter only these below values (that is available under "text" field). I want to use the `jq` command for this. I have tried this command, but it is resulting in an error:

`jq -r'.[].content.data[]["content-item"]'|jq -r '.[]| select (.text |startswith("^23.acmestable.0."))'`

Expected result:

```
23.acmestable.0.22
23.acmestable.0.23
23.acmestable.0.24
23.acmestable.0.25
```

Which is this JQ query runs for "hardcoded" value:

`'.[].content.data[]["content-item"]'|jq -r '.[]| select (.text=="23.acme.0.23")'`

and returns:

```
{
  "text": "23.acmestable.0.23"
}
```

Sample JSON:

```
[
   {
      "content": {
         "data": [
             {
               "content-item": [
                  {
                     "resourceURI": "https://acme.example.com/service/local/repositories/public/content/com/acme/acme-files/23.acmestable.0.0-SNAPSHOT/"
                  },
                  {
                     "relativePath": "/com/acme/acme-files/23.acmestable.0.0-SNAPSHOT/"
                  },
                  {
                     "text": "23.acmestable.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
                  },
                  {
                     "leaf": "false"
                  },
                  {
                     "lastModified": "2022-10-06 11:54:58.0 UTC"
                  },
                  {
                     "sizeOnDisk": "-1"
                  }
               ]
            },
             {
               "content-item": [
                  {
                     "resourceURI": "https://acme.example.com/service/local/repositories/public/content/com/acme/acme-files/23.acmestable.0.24/"
                  },
                  {
                     "relativePath": "/com/acme/acme-files/23.acmestable.0.24/"
                  },
                  {
                     "text": "23.acmestable.0.24"
                  },
                  {
                     "leaf": "false"
                  },
                  {
                     "lastModified": "2022-10-07 03:17:23.0 UTC"
                  },
                  {
                     "sizeOnDisk": "-1"
                  }
               ]
            },
             {
               "content-item": [
                  {
                     "resourceURI": "https://acme.example.com/service/local/repositories/public/content/com/acme/acme-files/23.acmestable.0.25/"
                  },
                  {
                     "relativePath": "/com/acme/acme-files/23.acmestable.0.25/"
                  },
                  {
                     "text": "23.acmestable.0.25"
                  },
                  {
                     "leaf": "false"
                  },
                  {
                     "lastModified": "2022-10-07 03:17:23.0 UTC"
                  },
                  {
                     "sizeOnDisk": "-1"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "content-item": [
                  {
                     "resourceURI": "https://acme.example.com/service/local/repositories/public/content/com/acme/acme-files/23.acmestable.0.22/"
                  },
                  {
                     "relativePath": "/com/acme/acme-files/23.acmestable.0.22/"
                  },
                  {
                     "text": "23.acmestable.0.22"
                  },
                  {
                     "leaf": "false"
                  },
                  {
                     "lastModified": "2022-10-07 03:17:23.0 UTC"
                  },
                  {
                     "sizeOnDisk": "-1"
                  }
               ]
            },
             {
               "content-item": [
                  {
                     "resourceURI": "https://acme.example.com/service/local/repositories/public/content/com/acme/acme-files/23.acmestable.0.23/"
                  },
                  {
                     "relativePath": "/com/acme/acme-files/23.acmestable.0.23/"
                  },
                  {
                     "text": "23.acmestable.0.23"
                  },
                  {
                     "leaf": "false"
                  },
                  {
                     "lastModified": "2022-10-07 03:17:23.0 UTC"
                  },
                  {
                     "sizeOnDisk": "-1"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just traverse and `select` in a single jq call. The `?` filters out the `null` values.

```bash
jq -r '.[].content.data[]."content-item"[].text | select(startswith("23.acmestable.0."))?'
```

```
23.acmestable.0.0-SNAPSHOT
23.acmestable.0.24
23.acmestable.0.25
23.acmestable.0.22
23.acmestable.0.23
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/LyLCztrbBEP)

Note: `startswith` takes a plain (sub)string, not a regular expression. Replace it with `test` to perform a regex matching instead. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/elVWJQ_Jqle)